# search on a shoestring postgres vs. elasticsearch

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-5, postgresql-9.6

I currently run the search backend for [helpmanual.io](https://helpmanual.io) on a [scaleway C1](https://www.scaleway.com/pricing/) server (2GB ram, 4 ARM cores, 50GB SSD). The search currently uses postgres 9.6's full text search but I'm considering migrating to elasticsearch.

**Question:** is elasticsearch 5.X likely to give a worthwhile query time improvement over postgres 9.X under these conditions?

Documents: ~30k documents varying from a few kb to I guess around 500kb. (The documents don't need to be stored, just the search vector, title and link)

Load: full text search, volume fairly low for now

Comment: You should really try it on your data to see what the actual performance is.  There may also be other considerations between switching between a fully functional database and elastic search.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. The search backend is just returning json for search queries, it has nothing to do with the rest of the site which is just served from S3.

Comment: In the end, I continued using postgres: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/helpmanual.io.search, the response time seems excellent, queries generally take <100ms occasionally longer if the search term is very common.